# Spring security error with access-denied-handler tag

Tags: spring, spring-security, access-denied

I added the access-denied-handler tag to redirect to an specific page when my app handles a `AccessDeniedException` but I have the error:

> Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative
> location [pgm-security-cas.xml] Offending resource: class path
> resource [spring/pgm-servlet.xml]; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
> Line 92 in XML document from class path resource
> [spring/pgm-security-cas.xml] is invalid; nested exception is
> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content
> was found starting with element 'sec:access-denied-handler'. One of
> '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":intercept-url}' is
> expected.

this is my xml:

```
<bean id="fsi"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="httpRequestAccessDecisionManager" />
    <property name="securityMetadataSource">
        <sec:filter-invocation-definition-source use-expressions="true">
            <sec:intercept-url pattern="/manageboxes" access="hasRole('A_READ_USER')" />
            <sec:access-denied-handler error-page="/accessDeniedPage" />
        </sec:filter-invocation-definition-source>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Somebody knows where is problem?

The definition of the filterChainProxy is:

```
<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <sec:filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
        <sec:filter-chain pattern="/xhtml/login/invalidLogin.xhtml*" filters="none" />
        <sec:filter-chain pattern="/j_spring_security_logout"
            filters="logoutFilter,fsi" />
        <sec:filter-chain pattern="/javax.faces.resource/*"
            filters="none" />
        <sec:filter-chain pattern="/**"
            filters="casAuthenticationFilter, casValidationFilter, wrappingFilter, sif, j2eePreAuthFilter, logoutFilter, fsi" />
    </sec:filter-chain-map>
</bean>
```

Comment: `<access-denied-handler>` is only allowed as a direct child of `<http>`. As the error message states it is no valid child of `<filter-invocation-definition-source>` (only `<intercept-url>` is valid).

Comment: Please show the definition of your `filterChainProxy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<access-denied-handler>` can't be placed inside `<filter-invocation-definition-source>`. You have to create an `exceptionTranslator`:

```
<bean id="exceptionTranslator"            class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
<property name="authenticationEntryPoint">
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
            p:loginFormUrl="/login" />
</property>
<property name="accessDeniedHandler">
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl"
    p:errorPage="/accessDenied" />
</property>
</bean>
```

and wire it into your `filterChainProxy`

```
<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <sec:filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
        <sec:filter-chain pattern="/**"
            filters="casAuthenticationFilter, casValidationFilter, wrappingFilter, sif,      j2eePreAuthFilter, logoutFilter, 
            exceptionTranslator,
            fsi" />
        </sec:filter-chain-map>
</bean>
```

Comment: Hi Dirk, thank you very much for your answer but, i don't understand how works the exceptionTranslator that you have written. In my case I want to handle the access to the manageboxes area in my app.

Comment: It works as supposed by you. If access is denied spring redirects to the `errorPage` url. That is `/accessDenied` in my example (i've simply copied it from my production code) and you should modify it to `accessDeniedPage` to align it with your `fsi`-bean.

Comment: That is: You remove `<sec:access-denied-handler error-page="/accessDeniedPage" />` from your fsi-bean, add the exceptionTranslator bean definition *and* add the exceptionTranslator to your filterChain (the second last entry in my example, just before the fsi filter).

Comment: Hi Dirk, thanks. Now I don't have errors and the AccessDeniedException is thrown but no handled. I've removed the access-denied-handler from my fsi-bean, I have added the exceptionTranslatorFilter definition and added it into my filterChain V_V

Comment: Hi again Dirk, I fixed it. The problem was that, and I will remember this forever, the order of filters matters. I had added my exceptionTranslatorFilter at the last of list of filters into the filter-chan... so I moved it behind my fsi and tachan! It works. Thank you very much for your help my friend!

Comment: @rlopezo You are welcome. Btw., you can look up the filter order in the docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html (see chapter 7.3).