# Custom filter position in spring security

Tags: java, spring, filter, spring-security

How can I insert multiple custom filters in the Spring Security chain at the top of the chain?

I can insert one by using `position="FIRST"` and `after="FIRST"` but how can I add two or three at the top of the chain?  If I try multiple `after="FIRST"` I get conflict errors that I cannot put multiple filters in the same position.

```
    <custom-filter ref="customExceptionJSONFilter" position="FIRST"/>
    <custom-filter ref="logHeadersFilter" after="FIRST"/>
    <custom-filter ref="thirdCustomFilter" after="FIRST"/>       <---- this causes a conflict
```

Is there any way of positioning based on another filter?  Or some way of saying "FIRST+1", "FIRST+2", etc?

Comment: You could omit the security namespace but manually configure spring security.

Comment: @DirkLachowski - Can you elaborate please?  I'm not sure what you are suggesting.

Comment: I'm out of office at the moment so only a short reply first. You will have to manually configure the FilterChainProxy. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/22716881/1686330 for a first impression. I will come back on this but it will take a while.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that is probably to wrap the filters you want to insert into a single `Filter`. You can copy the code from `VirtualFilterChain` in Spring Security to implement it: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/6be4e3a9fc99d676f367a5e9eed3ea61fbba122c/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/FilterChainProxy.java#L306

Comment: I realized that, but was hoping there was something I was missing.  When I looked at the ordinances in `org.springframework.security.config.http.SecurityFilters` for `FIRST` and saw that it was defined as `-MAXINT` and that there was 100 spots allowed between filter defns, I figured there must be a way to use the extra spots.  Just couldn't figure out how.  Also, I was surprised that Spring didn't provide a public form of `VirtualFilterChain` that I could use out of the box, so presumed there had to be something else.